# Url rewriting - as a directory

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am going to have a url like this
**www.example.com/user/James**

Instead of:
**www.example.com/user/?username=James**
using URL rewriting (.htaccsess)

I don't want the user to be redirected, just that `/user/James shows` `/user/?username=James` content. Does anybody have the answer?

Is it possible to use **www.example.com/James** instead of **www.example.com/user/James**?

My server language is PHP

Thank you and sorry for poor english :-)

Comment: See if this search helps  http://google.com/?q=htaccsess+restful

Comment: What is the WebServer / Language?

Comment: My server language is PHP

Comment: Is this apache? That's kind of important

Comment: Yes it is :-) I am using MAMP on my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using apache's mod_rewrite, add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (server root, where `/` goes to):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This won't redirect the browser which won't affect the URL in the browser's location bar.

Comment: Sorry, did not work. Using this code:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /p/?post=$1 [L,QSA]
I got a 404 error :(

Comment: @user2846191 and the htaccess file is in your document root? Are you sure the htaccess file is being read? (has proper permissions, you have `AllowOverride All` in your host setup)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Can the problem be that I'm running the website local on my computer (using MAMP?)?

Comment: It worked when I uploaded it to my website, instead using MAMP! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the following link

```
www.preparationweb.com/Aptitude/Discussion/index.php?qid=26
```

I like it to appear it as

```
www.preparationweb.com/Aptitude/Discussion/26
```

Can you please provide me the code to be placed in .htaccess file according to the provided link. I have a godaddy hosting.